# Adding a #suffix to a Drupal Product Form Payment Method Radio

Tags: forms

I have two radio buttons in my Drupal 7 product form. One for credit card and the other for 'send an invoice'. I'd like to add some text after each option but I don't know how.

In my hook_form_alter module this is what I'm attempting:

```
$form['commerce_payment']['payment_method']['#options']
['paypal_commerce_payment_paypal_wpp']['#suffix'] = 'text here';
```

However, this keeps throwing an error:

```
Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in 
drupal_validate_utf8() (line 1599 of 
/var/www/checkout/includes/bootstrap.inc).
Notice: Array to string conversion in format_string() (line 1550 of 
/var/www/checkout/includes/bootstrap.inc).
```

And under the two radio options it just says 'Array' next to yet another radio button. Obviously not what I want. I want the text 'text here' to appear right after the 'Credit Card' radio option.

I also tried targeting the 'suffix' with '`#field_suffix`' to no avail.

Any idea how to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here could be the type of element `$form['commerce_payment']['payment_method']['#options']['paypal_commerce_payment_paypal_wpp']` is.

Is paypal_commerce_payment_paypal_wpp the key of one your options?

Have you tried [#description](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#description)?

Comment: I think I see what you mean. That element is a String. I guess I want to append some HTML to the string. If I could change what the string says that would work even better. I tried #description but it gave me the same error.

Comment: Changing what the string says would be really easy

`$form['commerce_payment']['payment_method']['#options']['paypal_commerce_payment_paypal_wpp'] = 'my new string';`

Comment: Nevermind you were correct - it worked. Thank you!